# Open sidenav from external URL

Tags: angular, routes

I have a doubt, to know if it is possible to do (and how) the following: I have an `angular 6` app that displays a map. In this map, I render markers from a geoJSON. If I click a marker, the app opens a sidenav with marker's information. Well, here I have the problem:

The URL from the map is `http://example.com/#/pages/map`. Every marker has a unique ID ( something like this `11_39_6534`). I want to create an URL that opens the sidenav with specific information about the marker

```
http://example.com/#/pages/map/11_39_6534
```

Is similar to google maps. [Example](https://www.google.es/maps/place/Gran+V%C3%ADa/@40.4182362,-3.7048264,16.54z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0xd422887725ef2a1:0x32afa6604bc0f548!8m2!3d40.4198531!4d-3.7016067)

How can I do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a route like this :

`pages/map/:markerId'`

then in the component releated to your new route, in the `onInit` add this:

```
ngOnInit(){
   const markerId = this.activatedroute.snapshot.params['markerId'];
   //... function that trigger the toggle
}
```

If you can be more specific on the logic you've implemented for toggle the sidenav by clicking the marker, i can edit my answer in a better way. But it should be clear even in this simple way

Comment: It's a bit complicated explain how I open the sidenav, because I inject diferent components depending of the action. I followed this tutorial https://medium.com/@DenysVuika/dynamic-material-sidebar-in-angular-fe7013dabf5c

Comment: I understand, I can make you a Plunker example, but just to show how to catch the id you passed in the url with a simple logic (like a console.log) to show the catch

Comment: Fine! Thank you! How can I check if the route is active?

Comment: you will get `const markerId` undefined is the activatedRoute did not found the id passed into the url. So I suggest you to just do a check like this: if(!!markerId){ //executeLogic}

Comment: Hmm, this logic didn't work. Now I can get the id from URL, but if I put  if(!!markerId){ //executeLogic} the logic never execute. If I only put one  if(!markerId){ //executeLogic}, always execute the logic. And I need to use the url /pages/map, cause I have many functions running into this

Comment: Well, then you are not getting the value from the url, so your `markerId` should be undefined. Can you tell me what's inside `this.activatedroute.snapshot.params` in dubug mode?

Comment: Sure. With 'pages/map' == ``undefined``. With '/pages/map/11_33_1523' == ``undefined``  too. The code : ```let id_alteration;
    if (!!id_alteration) {
      id_alteration = this.activatedroute.snapshot.params['id_alteration'];
      console.log('HERE ->', id_alteration);
    }```

Comment: Please confirm that: Your new route is `path: 'pages/map/:markerId',
    component: YourComponent`, and you are doing the logic I've posted on `YourComponent`>`OnInit`, right?

Comment: ```{ path: 'map/:id_alteration', loadChildren: './map/map.module#MapModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard] }``` , doing it in ```onInit``` in ```map.component```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181144/discussion-between-jacopo-sciampi-and-aw3same).